# Optimize DELETE FROM mdl_grade_items_history

Tags: mysql, innodb, moodle

Last week I installed some additional database monitoring and have since come to discover that **a full 30% of our database load** is spent on a single query on a single table (which currently has some 6 million rows):

```
delete FROM mdl_grade_items_history WHERE timemodified < ?
```

In a testing environment, I tried to make some schema changes:

Running `EXPLAIN` on this query indicates that every time this query is run, a full table scan is done.

```
EXPLAIN DELETE FROM mdl_grade_items_history WHERE timemodified < '1490528405';
+----+-------------+-------------------------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table                   | partitions | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows   | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------------------------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | DELETE      | mdl_grade_items_history | NULL       | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 140784 |   100.00 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-------------------------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+----------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Checking `EXPLAIN` for a (very similar) `SELECT` query shows a similar situation.

```
EXPLAIN SELECT id FROM mdl_grade_items_history WHERE timemodified < '1490528405';
+----+-------------+-------------------------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table                   | partitions | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows   | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------------------------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | mdl_grade_items_history | NULL       | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 140784 |    33.33 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-------------------------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+----------+-------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.01 sec)
```

Checking the table definition, there does not seem to be an index on `timemodified`

```
SHOW INDEX FROM mdl_grade_items_history;
+-------------------------+------------+-------------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table                   | Non_unique | Key_name                | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+-------------------------+------------+-------------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| mdl_grade_items_history |          0 | PRIMARY                 |            1 | id          | A         |      140784 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| mdl_grade_items_history |          1 | mdl_graditemhist_act_ix |            1 | action      | A         |           2 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| mdl_grade_items_history |          1 | mdl_graditemhist_old_ix |            1 | oldid       | A         |       17170 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| mdl_grade_items_history |          1 | mdl_graditemhist_cou_ix |            1 | courseid    | A         |        1065 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| mdl_grade_items_history |          1 | mdl_graditemhist_cat_ix |            1 | categoryid  | A         |        2300 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| mdl_grade_items_history |          1 | mdl_graditemhist_sca_ix |            1 | scaleid     | A         |           6 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| mdl_grade_items_history |          1 | mdl_graditemhist_out_ix |            1 | outcomeid   | A         |           1 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| mdl_grade_items_history |          1 | mdl_graditemhist_log_ix |            1 | loggeduser  | A         |          30 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
+-------------------------+------------+-------------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

So I tried to add one (both via `CREATE INDEX` and `ALTER TABLE .. ADD INDEX`)

```
CREATE INDEX `mdl_gradeitemhist_tim_ix` ON `mdl_grade_items_history` (`timemodified`);
ALTER TABLE `mdl_grade_items_history` ADD INDEX `mdl_gradeitemhist_tim_ix` (`timemodified`);
```

In both instances, the SELECT query was affected (note the change in `type`)

```
EXPLAIN `SELECT` id FROM mdl_grade_items_history WHERE timemodified < '1490528405';
+----+-------------+-------------------------+------------+-------+--------------------------+--------------------------+---------+------+-------+----------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type | table                   | partitions | type  | possible_keys            | key                      | key_len | ref  | rows  | filtered | Extra                    |
+----+-------------+-------------------------+------------+-------+--------------------------+--------------------------+---------+------+-------+----------+--------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | mdl_grade_items_history | NULL       | range | mdl_gradeitemhist_tim_ix | mdl_gradeitemhist_tim_ix | 9       | NULL | 70206 |   100.00 | Using where; Using index |
+----+-------------+-------------------------+------------+-------+--------------------------+--------------------------+---------+------+-------+----------+--------------------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

But not the `DELETE` query.

```
EXPLAIN DELETE FROM mdl_grade_items_history WHERE timemodified < '1490528405';
+----+-------------+-------------------------+------------+------+--------------------------+------+---------+------+--------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table                   | partitions | type | possible_keys            | key  | key_len | ref  | rows   | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------------------------+------------+------+--------------------------+------+---------+------+--------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | DELETE      | mdl_grade_items_history | NULL       | ALL  | mdl_gradeitemhist_tim_ix | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 140412 |   100.00 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-------------------------+------------+------+--------------------------+------+---------+------+--------+----------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

What have I done wrong? What else could I try?

Comment: Would an Index not slow the DELETE down even more due to deletes causing indexes to change? Is there any foreign key relationships between your large table and other large tables? I believe those can slow down large deletes as well and it might work to remove them, delete and recreate them if that is the case.  Or can you delete in "batches" x-amount of records at a time using a loop?

Comment: @Fran There are, to my knowledge, no foreign keys. Changing the query to DELETE in batches is certainly on the table.

Answer (score 1):

- Low cardinality indexes (action, scaleid, outcomeid) are almost never used.  Get rid of them.
- Having a large number of single-column indexes is a red flag.  Please learn about the power and benefit of "composite" indexes.  (Not relevent for the select/delete mentioned here, but probably relevant for other queries.)
- Extra indexes on a table slightly slow down `INSERTs` and `DELETEs` since the indexes need to (eventually) be updated.
- Extra indexes slow down `UPDATEs` if an indexed column is modified.
- `CREATE INDEX` and `ALTER TABLE ADD INDEX` do the same thing; you probably have a redundant index now.
- The `EXPLAINs` are different because (1) `SELECT` and `DELETE` do different things and (2) `EXPLAIN` is not very sophisticated.
- Deleting a large number of rows takes a lot of effort -- Keep in mind that the deleted rows are hung onto in case of a `ROLLBACK`.  Only after `COMMIT` can the rows really be removed.  (With `autocommit=ON`, there is an implicit `COMMIT`.)

Tips on large deletes:

- [Deleting in chunks](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig)
- [Using `PARTITIONs` for very efficient deletion of time series](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint)